# Problem saving from inversed side of many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have two entities: `AudioPlaylist` and `AudioTrack`.

AudioPlaylist.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "AudioTrack", inversedBy = "audioPlaylists")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name = "audioplaylist_audiotrack")
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
protected $audioTracks;
```

AudioTrack.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "AudioPlaylist", mappedBy = "audioTracks")
 * 
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
 protected $audioPlaylists;
```

My problem is that when I call `$audioTrack->addAudioPlaylist($audioPlaylist)`, the `audioplaylist_audiotrack` table doesn't get updated. I'm expecting a new row to be added to the table signifying the relationship between the two entities. Everything works fine for the inverse though `$audioPlaylist->addAudioTrack($audioTrack)` adds a new row.

I'm making sure to persist `$audioTrack` and flush the entity manager, but no luck, so I assume there must be something wrong with my annotations (I'm using [this example from the Doctrine docs)](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably because you have not set the `cascade` property for your inverse side. You must define [cascading](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) explicitly for Doctrine2 to persist any related entities.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "AudioPlaylist",
 *                     mappedBy = "audioTracks",
 *                      cascade = {"persist", "remove"})
 * 
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
protected $audioPlaylists;
```

Make sure you also add your `AudioTrack` to `AudioPlaylist` as well, when calling `AudioTrack::addAudioPlaylist()`:

```
public function addAudioPlaylist(AudioPlaylist $playlist)
{
    $this->getAudioPlaylists()->add($playlist);
    $playlist->getAudioTracks()->add($this);
}
```

Comment: Adding `$playlist->getAudioTracks()->add($this);` to `addAudioPlaylist()` got it working, but the cascade options had no effect. It seems odd that I'd need to modify `addAudioPlaylist()` for this to work, though. Especially since it was auto-generated by Symfony

Comment: @arms I've had mixed results with the cascade options, sometimes they work and sometimes they don't. As for the auto-generation, it's not entirely perfect and I suggest using the [Doctrine2 manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/index.html) if you get stuck. You can read more about working with association management methods from [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-associations.html#association-management-methods).